# Java Bloomberg API using authentication by IP

Tags: java, bloomberg

I am trying to write some code to remotely grab some basic reference data from my Bloomberg terminal remotely.  Is this possible?  I have a setup with two separate PCs.  PC-1 has Bloomberg running on it, PC-2 does not.  Without installing Bloomberg on PC-2, is there a way I can have a Java application which gives the IP+user identity credentials of PC-1 and obtains some basic reference data?  Example code much appreciated.  I see AuthenticationByIp.java in the BB API but I can't get it working.  I don't think it is what I am looking for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that by calling the API directly from PC2.

You could have a service running on PC1 that relays queries from PC2 to the API, but that would be a breach of your Bloomberg contract, because you are only allowed to use data obtained from the API on the PC on which the Bloomberg terminal is installed.

Comment: I see.  I didn't realize that.  Can you point me to a reference that makes that clear?  I didn't see anything like that on the open bloomberg site.

Comment: It would be in your Bloomberg contract.